# MS CRM showModalDialog Access denied

Tags: dynamics-crm, lookup

i have a website. If i click a button, a crm lookup should be opened.
This works very well for my testuser, but if i login to another user, i get a "Access denied" error.

Does anyone have an idea?

best regards
alex

Answer (score 0):

Ok i fixed it.
Solution:

I open my custom website with a button-click in crm and showmodaldialog.
Now i give the document-object of crm as parameter to ShowModalDialog.

In my custom Website i open the lookup with

```
window.dialogArguments.parentWindow.LookupObjects(null, "single", 8, 0, null, "", null, null, null, null, null, null, id);
```

Now it works without an Access denied error